# What are some references for Fluid and Diffusion models in Queuing?

Tags: reference-request, queuing-theory, stochastic-process

In queuing theory and stochastic process, there are many papers that have applied fluid and diffusion models to approximate the original models. However, the concepts and basics of these models are not comprehensively discussed. I would be thankful if someone can recommend some references covering these topics as basic as possible.